# Incorrect timezone adjustment in moment.js and spacetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

My server is sending my Javascript client a timestamp in UTC. I'm currently in Mountain Time which is currently in daylight savings (GMT-7), but any timezone adjustment I do is only applying -6 offset.

To confirm that javascript is even aware of my timezone, I did the following:

`console.log(Date().toString());` which outputs the following: `Mon Nov 19 2018 12:13:28 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`. It's  clear that JS knows I am currently in GMT-7.

Now, my server is sending `2018-08-24T17:00:00`. So I parse it with moment.js, convert to local timezone and then format the result.

```
moment.utc(this.props.value).local().format('h:mm A')
```

The resulting value is `11:00 AM`. 17:00:00 - 7 offset is 10:00 which is 10:00 AM. Why is javascript converting into 11:00? I get the same result if I try the [spacetime](https://github.com/spencermountain/spacetime) library:

```
   const s = spacetime(this.props.value,'UTC')
    s.goto(spacetime().timezone().name);
    console.log(s.format('h:mm a')); // Also spits out 11:00 AM
```

If I manually adjust the moment object with the offset, it works correctly:

```
var m = moment.utc(this.props.value);
m.add(-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset(), 'minutes');
console.log(m.format('h:mm A')) // Outputs the correct time: 10:00 AM
```

Why is `moment` and `spacetime` both not adjusting my timezone correctly when Javascript is clearly aware of what timezone I'm in? The same problem occurs in both Chrome and Microsoft Edge. For now I will use the hacky workaround above, but I'd prefer to use the native methods so I'm curious as to why this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Mountain Standard Time is UTC-7
- Mountain Daylight Time is UTC-6
- It is currently November 19th, and DST is *not* in effect, so you currently get UTC-7
- For the date you gave, `2018-08-24T17:00:00`, DST *is* in effect, so you get UTC-6

Everything is working correctly.

In other words, it doesn't matter whether it is currently in effect or not, only whether it is/was/will be in effect for the date in question.

---

Regarding this part:

```
m.add(-(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset(), 'minutes');
```

Don't do that.  You aren't adjusting the time zone, you're picking a different moment in time.

Comment: Can you explain how you can tell that 2018-08-24T17:00:00 is DST? There is no timezone information in that timestamp.

Comment: I see the problem now. Thanks for your input!

Comment: From the time timestamp alone, you can't tell.  However, you said you were in Mountain time zone (Calgary, from your profile).  Refer to [this page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/calgary).  You can see that August in Calgary is on MDT (UTC-6).  It's not necessarily DST everywhere - but it is for you, at that date and time.